# pdfsharp in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, pdfsharp

I am new to visual c++. I am trying to save a label as pdf file in visual c++. I linked pdfsharp dll by add resources from properties. When i run the .exe file in my system, it doesnt give any error. But when the .exe is run in other systems it gives error telling
*"could not load file or assembly 'pdfSharp, version=1.31.1789.0, culture = neutral, publicKeytoken= f94615aa0424f9eb' or one of its dependencies"*

But when i add the pdfsharp in the folder where this .exe stays, it doesnt give any error. What could be the problem. What should i do to run without adding pdf dll in the .exe folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EXE that links to PDFsharp.dll cannot run without PDFsharp.dll. You can add PDFsharp.dll to a directory listed in the PATH environment variable if you do not want to have it in the EXE folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any option to create pdf file without linking the dll file to the project? I want the .exe to run as a stand alone application.

Comment: I haven't tried myself, but Google found a post that shows the use of IlMerge as a post-build step to get rid of one assembly - looks like it is worth a try (and maybe get rid of all DLL files): http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx  The EXE will not really be "stand alone" as the .NET framework will be needed.

Comment: Thanks. Will check with this.