# Could not load file or assembly in Brokered Component

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

**Background:** I'm using a brokered component in Visual Studio 2015 using the template and tutorial provided [here](https://xamltips.wordpress.com/2016/01/07/brokered-component-starter-kit-for-uwp-app/comment-page-1/)

**Problem:** When I try to add nuget packages like PdfSharp or iTextSharp to the server component of the project I get the following error at runtime:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'PdfSharp, Version=1.50.4000.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f94615aa0424f9eb' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

on the first line where the package is referenced, in this case it was this line:

> PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();

**What I've Tried:** I replicated the problem with a new brokered component project. I also started a console application where I made the settings the same as the server component (other than output type; server is to class library and console application to exe) and the references the same (other than the Windows reference in the server component). I then added the PdfSharp reference to the console application and it worked, so it's just the brokered component. I have also tried to change the "Specific Version" and "Copy Local" attributes of the reference to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pdfsharp in visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559789/pdfsharp-in-visual-c)